# Yii Pagination not remember the dropdown list value

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I have some problem about pagination in Yii ,When I click on the next page button It doesn't remember value and I must choose the dropdown list again for showing detail ;What should I do/ Thank you for all answer

Comment: Add select value to pagination links with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

store selected value to a session, then use the session for condition checking